# How to limit the memory usage of a script?

Tags: bash, debian

I use a script that consumes a lot of ram memory to such an extent that it freezes my computer and gives an error.

How could you limit the memory usage of this particular script?

I use debian 9 (linux)

thanks.

this is the basic script

```
path="/home/xxx"
mesMenosUnDia=$(date +%m --date='-1 month')
fecha=$(date +"%Y-$mesMenosUnDia-%d")

echo "find"
list=$(find /home/xxx -type f)
listArray=($list)


for i in "${listArray[@]}"
do
        onlyDate=$(echo $i | grep -P '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}' -o)
        if [[  $onlyDate < $fecha ]];then

                rm $i
        else

        fi
done
```

Comment: Add your script to your question.

Comment: its added, its basic

Comment: By the way, limiting the usable memory with `ulimit` does not solve your real problem.

Comment: Instead of saving the result of `find` in a variable (*and* an array), couldn’t you pipe it to a `while read …`?

Comment: @Cyrus so ulimit doesn't limit the memory usage of a script like op asked? When does ulimit work and when it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the maximum memory to be used with ulimit. The drawback is that the script will hit the limit and die. But your computer will not hang, because when the script asks for too much memory, it will be killed.

You script is using too much memory because you are storing too many things in memory. Specifically, you grab the output of the find command into a variable and the you copy all of this data into an array, so the whole content gets duplicated.

Instead of keeping everything in memory, put it in disk.

```
path="/home/xxx"
mesMenosUnDia=$(date +%m --date='-1 month')
fecha=$(date +"%Y-$mesMenosUnDia-%d")

echo "find"
find /home/xxx -type f > tmp


for i in $(<tmp)
do
        onlyDate=$(echo $i | grep -P '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}' -o)
        if [[  $onlyDate < $fecha ]];then

                rm $i
        else

        fi
done

rm tmp
```

Comment: thank you, it was that, I have already solved it.
thank you very much